# lualatex resets text colour on new pages

Tags: color, luatex

I updated texlive 2021 yesterday and one of the updates seems to reset the text colour on new pages when you use lualatex. I checked with pdflatex and xelatex and they don't seem to have the same problem. I don't recall if the text colour in the footnotes were set by `\color{TextCoulor}` before I updated texlive.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{PageCoulor}{RGB}{70, 70, 70}
\definecolor{TextCoulor}{RGB}{225, 225, 225}
\AtBeginDocument
{
    \pagecolor{PageCoulor}
    \color{TextCoulor}
}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will look. For now you could load luacolor.

Comment: It is a bug, a \reset@color too much. I will make an update.